# How to get information of .jar file in python-magic

Tags: python, python-magic

I have a folder full of jar, html, css, exe type file. How can I check the file?

I already run "file" command on *NIX and using python-magic. but the result is all like this.

`test : Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract`

How can I get information specifically like `test : jar` only using using magic number.

How do I do like this?

Comment: All jar files are zip files - you need to extract the contents and determine manually whether they can be understood by Java, or just trust that the file name extension of `.jar` marking them as `jar` files is true.

Answer (score 0):

While not required, most JAR files have a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file contained within them. You could check for the existence of this file, after checking if it's a zip file:

```
import zipfile

def zipFileContains(zipFileName, pathName):
    f = zipfile.ZipFile(zipFileName, "r")
    result = any(x.startswith(pathName.rstrip("/")) for x in f.namelist())
    f.close()

    return result

print zipFileContains("test.jar", "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")
```

However, it might be better to just check if it's a zip file that ends in `.jar`.

Magic alone won't do it for you, since a JAR is literally just a zip file. Read more about the format [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)).